# A sequence of list in F#?

Tags: list, f#, sequence

I have to write a function that start from a infinite sequence and returns like this :

input sq0 = {x0,x1,x2,x3,...xn}

output sequence -> { [x0] , [x0;x1] , [x0;x1;x2] [x0;x1;x2;x3] ...}

can you help me please?

i've tried this

```
let rec pref sq = seq {
     yield [Seq.nth 0 sq] 
     let x1 = Seq.nth 1 sq 
     yield [x1] @ [x0]
     yield! pref Seq.skip 2 sq
}
```

Comment: thank you everybody for your replies :) very usefull!

Comment: if one of the answers is adequately answers your question you should mark it as correct (see the little check mark to the left of the answer).

Answer (score 4):

You can use the function `Seq.scan`:

```
let createSeq s =
    s
    |> Seq.scan (fun x y -> x @ [y]) []
    |> Seq.skip 1
```

Comment: You could change append to cons and add a call to `Seq.map List.rev` to make it lazier.

Comment: Yes, good tip. I just wanted to show a very basic solution. There are many ways to optimize it.

Answer (score 3):

This works quite well but probably could be more efficient:

```
let input = 
    Seq.initInfinite (fun i -> sprintf "x%i" i)

let output = 
    input 
    |> Seq.mapi (fun i _ -> input |> Seq.take (i + 1) |> Seq.toList)
```

Comment: The only issue is that it's limited to int range.

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing wrong with a bit of mutability.

```
let gen xs = 
    let ra = ResizeArray()
    seq{    for x in xs do
                ra.Add x
                yield Seq.toList ra }

gen ["x0";"x1";"x2";"x3";"x4"]
|> printfn "%A"
```

Output:

```
seq [["x0"]; ["x0"; "x1"]; ["x0"; "x1"; "x2"]; ["x0"; "x1"; "x2"; "x3"]; ...]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you already have the sequence of element to accumularte, gustavo's answer is not bad.

Otherwise, this recursive definition can work as well.

```
let rec createSeq = Seq.scan List.append List.empty init 
and      init     = seq {yield [1]; yield! createSeq}

let l = createSeq  |> Seq.take 5 |> Seq.toArray
```

Be mindful that Sequence is an interface, so many performance profile exists depending on the implementation and access pattern used.

Answer (score 0):

If performance is what you're after then this is what you want from both a time perspective and a memory usage perspective (this is a slimmed down version of [`Seq.scan`](https://github.com/fsharp/fsharp/blob/master/src/fsharp/FSharp.Core/seq.fs#L1146) from the compiler):

```
let scan z (source : seq<'T>) = 
    seq { let zref : ('T list ref) = ref z
          yield !zref
          use ie = source.GetEnumerator() 
          while ie.MoveNext() do
              zref := ie.Current :: !zref 
              yield !zref }

let input = Seq.initInfinite (fun i -> sprintf "x%i" i)

let createSeqCustom s =
    s
    |> scan []
    |> Seq.skip 1

> System.GC.Collect()
> let l = input |> createSeq  |> Seq.take 2000 |> Seq.toArray

Real: 00:00:00.007, CPU: 00:00:00.000, GC gen0: 0, gen1: 0, gen2: 0
```

Compared to the next fastest answer:

```
let createSeq s =
    s
    |> Seq.scan (fun x y -> x @ [y]) []
    |> Seq.skip 1

> System.GC.Collect()
> let l2 = input |> createSeq |> Seq.take 2000 |> Seq.toArray

Real: 00:00:00.293, CPU: 00:00:00.296, GC gen0: 6, gen1: 4, gen2: 0
```

The important difference being the garbage collections. This implementation will also handle larger sequences (notice 200,000 items being taken):

```
> System.GC.Collect()
> let l = input |> createSeqCustom  |> Seq.take 200000 |> Seq.toArray

Real: 00:00:00.406, CPU: 00:00:00.406, GC gen0: 11, gen1: 5, gen2: 0
```

Whereas the other implementations run out of memory on much smaller inputs (notice 20,000 items being taken):

```
> let l2 = input |> createSeq |> Seq.take 20000 |> Seq.toArray

System.OutOfMemoryException: Exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException' was thrown.
Stopped due to error
```

Comment: I realized that you have your lists in the opposite order from how this will work - `{ [x0] , [x0;x1] ... }` vs `{ [x0] , [x1;x0] ... }`.  If that is an issue you can change `zref := ie.Current :: !zref` to `zref := !zref @ [ie.Current]`.  You lose a lot of performance ( `Real: 00:00:00.290, CPU: 00:00:00.265, GC gen0: 6, gen1: 2, gen2: 0` for 2000 items ), but its still the fastest solution.